# How share data between widget in PageView?

Tags: flutter

I would like to make a 4 step form in a PageView. There are 4 widgets each corresponding to a stage. Each widget has a TextField and a button to go to the next page. On the last widget the button must retrieve the 4 values ​​of the Textfields to be able to save them. How can I do ?

````
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    Size _screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,

      body: PageView(
        controller: controller,
        scrollDirection: scrollDirection,
        pageSnapping: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          TitleInput(pcontainer: widget.pcontainer, controller: controller),
          DescriptionInput(pcontainer: widget.pcontainer, controller: controller),
          EstimationPage(pcontainer: widget.pcontainer, controller: controller),
          ImageCapture()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }```

//Button to go to next page:

Widget showNextPage(PageController controller, String topicTitle) {
  return new Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 45.0, 12.0, 0.0),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 60.0,
        width: 70,
        child: new RaisedButton(
          elevation: 5.0,
          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: new Text('Suivant',
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white)),
          onPressed: () => controller.nextPage(curve: Curves.ease, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300)),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This specific requirement can be fulfilled by creating a Data Model object to hold all the required data and passing this object through each widget to update respective data.

For example:

```dart
class DataModel {
  String fullName;
  String aboutInfo;
  String contactDetails;
}
```

and then Pass the Model's instance(`_dataModel`) as below:

`mainWidget` calls =>`fullNameWidget(_dataModel) // updates only fullName`

`fullNameWidget` calls =>`descriptionWidget(_dataModel) // updates only aboutInfo`

`descriptionWidget` calls =>`contactWidget(_dataModel) // updates only contactDetails`

`contactWidget` calls =>`finalWidget(_dataModel) // uses data collected in the _dataModel`

The important thing is that you make sure to pass the same model instance in each widget to update its respective field and then use the updated data from the instance to go ahead and save it in the last step.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer, however how the first widget can call the second since all the widgets are called in the main widget by a widget list?

Comment: oh, I didn't notice the list hierarchy. This makes it even easier in the list of widgets approach. Just pass the same `_dataModel` in the widgets. In `PagView` you can change the page by using [`animatePageTo()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController/animateToPage.html) in page controller.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest you an alternative solution: rather than using a PageView, you could try the [Stepper](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html) widget.

[image]

You can define the steps that indicate a sequential order of events that must happen and, of course, it's very customizable. Here's the basic skeleton of how you'd use this widget:

```
Stepper(
    steps: [
        Step(
            title: Text("Step number 1"),
            content: Text("widgets"),
        ),
        Step(
            title: Text("Step number 2"),
            content: Text("widgets"),
        ),
    ],
)
```

There is a very good article on [medium](https://medium.com/flutteropen/flutter-widgets-16-stepper-485ad8d1a248) that shows many tips for this widget.

---

I think that if you have an ordered series of steps, you should really try this widget as it is easy to use and very intuitive for the user.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use the Static Variable

```
// Define the Static Variable in Global class you can use any name
class Global{
static String s1,s2,s3,s4;
}
```

you can Assign the Values by

```
Global.s1 = "someValue";
```

you can Access the Value by

```
print(Global.s1);
```